# Is it possible to trace a single method with dotTrace?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-7.0, jetbrains-rider, dottrace

I am running JetBrains dotTrace 2023.3. I need to trace wall-clock per line of a particular method (line-by-line mode).

It is extremely slow. Is there a way to set dotTrace to only measure a single method?

*.NET7 WPF app*

Comment: I don't think so. If the method is that big, though, that probably calls for breaking it up anyway. That said, if you step through the method, VS will give you the time between steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You add filters with desired method names - see the picture
[image]

Comment: Nice! I learned something. :)